# I'm new to working with static/shared libraries in Windows. Please confirm that I understand things correctly

Tags: c++, linux, windows, visual-studio, dynamic-linking

A little background --- I'm a fairly inexperienced programmer, and I just started my first coding job at a small business that uses a pretty limited development platform to create touchscreen bar/casino games.  The IDE was designed to be used in Ubuntu, but *for whatever reason* some of our developers use a Windows port.

Anyway, I wrote a plugin (shared library, **.so** file) which allows our Linux programmers to play MIDI files using the Fluidsynth API (software-synthesizer).  I'm trying to write an equivalent **.dll** file for our Windows programmers, but I'm not very familiar with the environment.

I've spent some time playing with Microsoft Visual Studio, and I'd like to make sure I have a basic understanding of how its static/dynamic libraries and object files work before I dig too deep.  Here are some of my impressions, please confirm that my noob self is on right track.

1) A **.obj** file in Windows is equivalent to a **.o** file in Linux.

2) A **.lib** file in Windows is equivalent to a **.a** file (static library) in Linux.

3) A **.dll** file in Windows is equivalent to a **.so** (shared/dynamic library) in Linux.

4) A compiled header is **not** strictly required when linking objects/libraries.

5) Linking against a **.dll** *requires* the use of some import library **.lib**, which isn't the case in Linux.  Why?

6) A "Release" build in VS gives me the same functionality as a "Debug" build, minus some debugging features with which gives the former a smaller size.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `4)` A (pre)compiled header is a compiler artifact, it is never required for linking. `5)` Linking against a stable import .lib helps with predictable builds (and requirements thereof). That said, it is technically possible to generate an import .lib from a .dll. `6)` Plus additional optimizations in the release build.